# using quoted expressions and arrays in julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am having some trouble dealing with the differences between an array indexed at a spot and a the item at that spot in a quoted expression can be seen with this simple example:

```
julia> A=[:(2+3),:(4),:(9-8)];
julia> t=A[1];
julia> eval(quote 
       @show isequal($A[1],$t)
       @show $A[1]
       @show $t
       end)
isequal((Any[:(2 + 3),4,:(9 - 8)])[1],2 + 3) = false
(Any[:(2 + 3),4,:(9 - 8)])[1] = :(2 + 3)
2 + 3 = 5
5
```

I need to programatically access the indecies of `A` so I cannot simply use `t` for my application. So, something like this won't work:

```
julia> A=[:(2+3),:(4),:(9-8)];

julia> eval(quote
       for i in 1:2
       @show $(A[i])
       end
       end)
ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined
```

But, for my application to work which is detailed [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/creating-a-macro-for-defining-differential-equation-constraints-in-nloptcontrol-jl/4023/10) I need something (perhaps a temporary variable, which I tried unsuccessfully..) to equal `t`. Also, unfortunately I cannot just use `eval`. Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to interpolate all of `$(A[1])`, instead of as now apply `[1]` on `$A`

```
eval(quote
          @show isequal($(A[1]),$t)
          @show $(A[1])
          @show $t
      end)
isequal(2 + 3, 2 + 3) = true
2 + 3 = 5
2 + 3 = 5
5
```

Comment: thank you for you comment. The problem with this is that if this is being done in a loop and `1` is some variable, it will not be available:                  julia> eval(quote
       for i in 1:2
       @show $(A[i])
       end
       end)
ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined

Comment: Can you update your example to actually show the problem, then?